# My google maps polygon boundary and zoom is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been struggling with using bound with my polygons... it seemed to work when I only had markers
I am a complete beginner to maps so any help would be appreciated!
I know I am putting hard coded long and latitudes up front but I am not sure how to update it later. I thought my last line of code was supposed to do that?

```
function initialize() {
    var projpoints = tempstr.split("|");
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-26.6532808494364, 27.8769719868429 ),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var pt = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < projpoints.length; j++) {
        pt=[];
        var latlongpoints=projpoints[j].split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < latlongpoints.length; i++) { 
            var lat = (latlongpoints[i].split(" "));
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[1],lat[0]);
            pt.push(latlng);
            bounds.extend(latlng);
            var shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: pt,
                strokeColor: '#000000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,                    
                fillColor: '#808080',                    
                fillOpacity: 0.35    
            });

            shape.setMap(map);    
        }  

        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(),map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as doing `bounds.extend`, you probably also need to do a `map.fitBounds(bounds);` at the end, after your loops.

And your call to map.setCenter is incorrect.  This function only takes one parameter, a LatLng.  You're passing it two.  I'm assuming you want to do:

```
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds);
```

Although there is no getBoundsZoomLevel function on the map object that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you very much! This pretty much worked... I think my only other problem is my actual data..